# Rethrow from a function in the catch block

Tags: c++, exception

In this case, I have want to perform some actions based on the exception thrown and then re-throw the exception. Is this recommended - My aim is to do some work based on the exception thrown and rethrow it and have the application crash and generate dump that have the call stack in the exception.

```
class Foo
{
public:

void HandleException(const std::exception& ex)
{
    // Log, report some metrics
    throw;
}

void Work(//Some inputs)
{
     try
     {
          // trying doing some work
     }
     catch (const std::exception& ex)
     {
          // This is really an exceptional situation, and the exception should be thrown which  
          // cause the exe to abort and create dump.
          // Intention is to preserve call stack and have it in dump.
          HandleException(ex);
     }
}
}
```

Let me add another note to the question: When I have HandleException as a lambda function, throw in the lambda causes exception. Do I need to capture some state and how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

When you catch an exception you have two options:

- Achieve the original goal (contract) in some way, e.g. by retrying.
- Report failure by throwing.

Rethrowing the original exception is one way to implement the second bullet point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is valid. **BUT** it is also dangerous.

If you call `throw;` with no parameters and there is no exception currently in flight this will result in a call to `std::terminate()`. The problem with your current code is that anybody can call the function even when they are not in a catch block (which would result in termination).

So you may want to validate that an exception is propogating:

```
void HandleException(const std::exception& ex)
{
    // Log, report some metrics
    if (std::uncaught_exception()) {
        throw;
    }
    // Maybe put an else here.
}
```

Also worth reading: [GotW #47: Uncaught Exceptions](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm)